# suppress unit display in label

Tags: asp.net, label

I usually use this syntax to display the unit symbol in a label: ej. 5'230 €

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TotalAmount","{0:#,###.##}&nbsp;€") %>' id="LabelTotal"/>
```

The ugly thing about is that the symbol is displayed even if the value is null or empty. Then I would like the symbol just to be suppressed.

Anyone has an idea how to do that?
Martin

Comment: Why don't you use codebehind?

Comment: I probably will if I can't solve this with a snippet. This label is used in a GridView and the OnRowDataBound event is already packed with code, so that I rather would do it in the markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following snippet

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("TotalAmount")) > 0 ? string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("TotalAmount"))) : string.Empty %>' id="LabelTotal"/>
```

If the value that is to be evaluated can contain `null` values, you need to check for `IsNullOrEmpty` first before conversion.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("TotalAmount").ToString()) ? Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("TotalAmount")) > 0 ? string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("TotalAmount"))) : string.Empty : string.Empty %>' id="Label1"/>
```

Comment: But it doesn't work for negative Numbers. I tried Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("LineAmount")) != 0, but then it throws: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

Comment: Negative values yes, NULL values no. If those values can also be `null`, then there has to be a `IsNullOrEmpty` validation also before converting to decimal. See update

Comment: Ok, now it's working except that you have to replace >0 by !=0, otherwise everything negative is just wiped out.